# How to use Factory methods with larger aggregates in Domain Driven Design?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, factory-pattern

I am using **Domain Driven Design** in one of my bounded Contexts and i am using the **Factory** methods to create my domain aggregates and enforce my business rules and invariants but my issue is that sometimes i have large aggregates with a lot of properties and most of these properties are just data properties not behavioral ones that will not affect the state of the aggregate so, it is a nightmare to use factory methods to fill all these properties, Please advice me on how to do that with best practices ?

```
public async Task CreateEmployeeAsync(CreateOrUpdateEmployeeInput input)
    {
        Guard.ArgumentNotNull(input.Employee, nameof(input.Employee));
        var employeeDto = input.Employee;
        Address address = null;
        if (employeeDto.Address != null)
            address = new Address(employeeDto.Address.Street, employeeDto.Address.City, employeeDto.Address.State,
                employeeDto.Address.Country, employeeDto.Address.ZipCode);

        var employee = Employee.Create(employeeDto.FirstName, employeeDto.LastName, employeeDto.Email,
            employeeDto.DateOfJoining, employeeDto.DepartmentId, employeeDto.EmployeeType,
            employeeDto.ReportTo, employeeDto.Title, employeeDto.AllowSystemAccess, address);

        //These properties are just data properties, they will not affect the state of the aggregate
        //This is a nightmare to fill each one hand by hand or even using Factory
        employee.MobilePhone = input.Employee.MobilePhone;
        employee.WorkPhone = input.Employee.WorkPhone;
        employee.MaritalStatus = input.Employee.MaritalStatus;
        await _employeeRepository.InsertAsync(employee);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Are you asking if there is a more automated way to fill the properties than to write the code yourself? Or are you asking if it is okay if you leave some properties out?

Comment: I mean i need an automated way to fill these properties but fill only the properties that will affect the aggregate using factory methods

Comment: Can you show us some example code?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Have you considered using something like [Automapper](https://automapper.org/)?

Comment: Automapper isn't recommended to be used to create aggregates in ddd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "data properties" like mobile phone and work phone are part of the state of the aggregate. And there is business rules related to them. ex: phone number needs to be valid. MaritalStatus can be one of 3 predefined values, WorkPhone is not required ...

These properties need to be validated when creating the Employee object.
What I can suggest is to add them in the constructor.
In this case your domain model has many properties and there is no way to avoid setting them. I don't recommend something automated cause it will somehow hide some of the properties. The next developer who will be working with this code will be like: "I can't see where is the mobile phone being set " and this will increase the cognitive load when working on that part of the code. You will need to know about the domain model and the automapper or the tool used to autofill the properties in order to understand what is going on.

Having many properties in not necessarily a bad thing. If you want to improve your aggregate design you can group some of the properties in a new value object if that make sense to your business. You can create for example a ContactInfo value object that will contain email and phone numbers.